# Variable not working (no idea why) javascript

Tags: javascript

I need my variable to print out. I'm unsure why this is happening, its based around the underscore variable in my hangman game in the very last parts of the snipper HTML below. More specifically the part right below me.

```
//list of words
        var wordList = ["apple", "peach", "pear", "mango", "banana", "paper", "pens", "laptop", "desk", "chair", "star", "sky", "moon", "sun", "planets"];

    //picking a random word from the list
        var word = wordList[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordList.length)];

function replaceAt(str,index,chr) {
        if(index != -1) {
            str =  str.substr(0,index) + chr + str.substr(index+1);
        }
        return str;
    }

//checking if enter is pressed
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {                     
        if( event.keyCode == 13 ) {

//checking if letter is in the word
            alert(word);

            alert(underscore + " " + letter + " " + word.indexOf(letter));

            underscore = replaceAt(underscore, word.indexOf(letter * 2), letter);

            context.clearRect(canvas.width * 0.4, canvas.height * 0.3, canvas.width *0.7, canvas.height * 70);
            context.font = '50pt Calibri';
            context.textAlign = 'center';
            context.fillStyle = '#E2E2E3';
            context.fillText(underscore, canvas.width * 0.5, canvas.height * 0.70);


        }
    });
```

I'm horrible at JavaScript and am new to it. Thanks in advance for tolerating my annoyance.

```css
/* Hangman Game CSS File */
body
{
 background-color: #1B264F;
}

#main {
 background-color: #5386E4;
 height: 97vh; 
    width: 95vw;
    vertical-align: middle;

}
canvas {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
}

/* colour scheme hex 

lightest blue: #5386E4;
middle blue: #274690;
darkest  blue: #1B264F;
black color: #070707;
white color: #E2E2E3;

*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Hangman by Lachlan Teale</title> 
  <meta name="description" content="Lachlan Teale's Hangman Game 2015">
  <meta name="keywords" content="hangman, lachlan, teale, Javascript">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="author" content="Lachlan Teale">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
 <canvas id="main" width="1920" height="1080" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>

 <script type="text/javascript">

 //setting variables
  var canvas = document.getElementById('main');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
       var underscore = "";
       var letter;
       var complete = false;

 //list of words
  var wordList = ["apple", "peach", "pear", "mango", "banana", "paper", "pens", "laptop", "desk", "chair", "star", "sky", "moon", "sun", "planets"];

 //picking a random word from the list
  var word = wordList[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordList.length)];

 //print out the underscores for the number of letters
  for (i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
   var underscore = underscore + "_ ";
  }

  context.font = '50pt Calibri';
       context.textAlign = 'center';
       context.fillStyle = '#E2E2E3';
       context.fillText(underscore, canvas.width * 0.5, canvas.height * 0.70);

    //correct letter text
       context.font = 'bold 30pt Calibri';
       context.textAlign = 'center';
       context.fillStyle = '#E2E2E3';
       context.text
       context.fillText("Correct Letters", canvas.width * 0.08, canvas.height * 0.05);

    //Wrong Letter text
       context.font = 'bold 30pt Calibri';
       context.textAlign = 'center';
       context.fillStyle = '#E2E2E3';
       context.text
       context.fillText("Wrong Letters", canvas.width - (canvas.width * 0.08), canvas.height * 0.05);

 //checking which button is pressed
  window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
   if ( event.keyCode >= 65 && event.keyCode <= 90 ) {
       context.clearRect(0, canvas.height * 0.80, canvas.width, canvas.height);  
          letter = String.fromCharCode( event.keyCode ).toLowerCase();
          context.font = '50pt Calibri';
         context.textAlign = 'center';
         context.fillStyle = '#E2E2E3';
         context.fillText(letter, canvas.width * 0.5, canvas.height * 0.85);
        }
  });

 //checking if back key is pressed
  document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {                     
      if ( event.keyCode == 8 ) {              
       context.clearRect(0, canvas.height * 0.80, canvas.width, canvas.height); 
      }
     });

 //function for replacing letter
  function replaceAt(str,index,chr) {
      if(index != -1) {
       str =  str.substr(0,index) + chr + str.substr(index+1);
   }
   return str;
  }

 //checking if enter is pressed
       document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {                     
      if( event.keyCode == 13 ) {

    //checking if letter is in the word
       alert(word);

    alert(underscore + " " + letter + " " + word.indexOf(letter));

    underscore = replaceAt(underscore, word.indexOf(letter * 2), letter);

    context.clearRect(canvas.width * 0.4, canvas.height * 0.3, canvas.width *0.7, canvas.height * 70);
       context.font = '50pt Calibri';
         context.textAlign = 'center';
         context.fillStyle = '#E2E2E3';
         context.fillText(underscore, canvas.width * 0.5, canvas.height * 0.70);

          
   }
     }); 

  
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please...a **small** self-contained example (it's also helpful to isolate problem)...

Comment: What do you mean by **//checking if letter is in the word**? `alert(word);`can't work... word isn't defined

Comment: I apologize @gr3g. I forgot to include that in the code. It is actually defined in the whole thing. I have edited the snippet to include this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you shouldn't redefine your underscore variable in your for loop.

ie, dont do

```
for (i = 0; i < word.length; i++)   {
        var underscore = underscore + "_ ";
    }
```

instead

```
for (i = 0; i < word.length; i++)   {
        underscore += "_ ";
    }
```

thats just the most glaring thing i noticed..

in the future it helps to accompany your question with a jsfiddle example.  you can get quicker and more accurate responses if we can quickly repro what you're seeing.

Comment: I completely didn't notice that. Thanks for the pickup.